# Como adicionar uma classe em um elemento HTML, por meio do JavaScript. No meu caso, preciso adicionar uma classe no elemento h1 abaixo

Tags: javascript, html, classes, dom, elementos

Preciso adicionar uma classe no elemento H1

```
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  h1.textContent = "Me Ajuda";
  p.textContent = "Preciso adicionar uma classe";
  div.appendChild(h1);
  div.appendChild(p);
  console.log(div);
```

Comment: Caso alguma resposta solucionou seu problema não deixe de marcá-la como aceita. Veja como e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0):

**Editado**

Apenas substitua "sua-class" pelo nome da sua class. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
  var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  h1.classList.add("sua-class");
  h1.textContent = "Me Ajuda";
  p.textContent = "Preciso adicionar uma classe";
  div.appendChild(h1);
  div.appendChild(p);
  console.log(div);
```

**Explicando o uso de classList:**

A propriedade classList retorna o (s) nome (s) da classe de um elemento, como um objeto DOMTokenList.

Essa propriedade é útil para adicionar, remover e alternar classes CSS em um elemento.

A propriedade classList é somente leitura, no entanto, você pode modificá-la usando os métodos add() e remove().

**Refefência:** [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)

Comment: Para quê serve o "classList"?

Comment: A propriedade classList retorna o (s) nome (s) da classe de um elemento, como um objeto DOMTokenList.

Essa propriedade é útil para adicionar, remover e alternar classes CSS em um elemento.

A propriedade classList é somente leitura, no entanto, você pode modificá-la usando os métodos add () e remove ().

Refefência: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp

Comment: @alan seu bom editar a resposta e juntar uma explicação!

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Buscar elemento pai
var elemento_pai = document.body;

 var div = document.createElement("div");
  var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  h1.textContent = "Te ajudei! :)";
  p.textContent = "Adicionei uma classe a tag h1";
  div.appendChild(h1);
  div.appendChild(p);
  
  h1.classList.add("classH1");
  
  elemento_pai.appendChild(div);
```

```css
.classH1
{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

> Para adicionar uma ou mais classes em um elemento HTML, basta selecioná-lo e chamar o método classList.add, passando uma String como argumento. É interessante notar que podemos adicionar múltiplas classes de uma só vez. Para isso, informe os nomes das classes que deseja adicionar separados por vírgula. Exemplo: `h1.classList.add( 'classH1', 'class2', 'class3' );`

```js
// Buscar elemento pai
var elemento_pai = document.body;

 var div = document.createElement("div");
  var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  h1.textContent = "Te ajudei! :)";
  p.textContent = "Adicionei várias classes a tag h1";
  div.appendChild(h1);
  div.appendChild(p);
  
  h1.classList.add( 'classH1', 'class2', 'class3' )
  
  elemento_pai.appendChild(div);
```

```css
.classH1
{
color:red;
}
.class2
{
font-size:12px;
}
.class3
{
letter-spacing : 6px;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

[image: compatibilidade]

[Para algo mais detalhado (compatibilidade) - Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist)

Answer (score -5):

Você pode fazer também da seguinte forma
h1.className = "nomeDaClasse":

Comment: Tem que tomar cuidado. Isso que descreveu não adiciona uma classe, isso substitui as existentes. Pode funcionar nos casos em que esteja tratando de uma classe só, mas vai dar problema se o elemento contiver alguma outra já. Veja as outras respostas para entender melhor.